# how do you find and count how many of a specific slice of a string exists in a variable string?

Tags: python

```
s=input(str('Enter String:'))
bobcount=0
for letter in s:
    if s[s.find(letter) : s.find(letter)+3]=='bob':
        bobcount+=1
print(bobcount)
```

It seems to me my code is right but it outputs the wrong answer. can anyone help? in this instance im trying to output how many times 'bob' occurs in a string

Comment: `.find()` always returns the first instance

Comment: `my_string.count('bob')`?

Comment: you can use `str.count()` is you don't want overlapping counts, e.g. `'AAA'.count('AA')`, what should the output be 1 or 2

Comment: @Chris_Rands that's not useful here, but it also takes a start and a stop index so you could store the index at which you found something and use that to "skip" any already handled match.

Comment: Without that erroneous use of `find`, you'd have `for letter in range(len(s)): if s[letter:letter+3] ..`. That returns `3` for `'bob bobob'` -- is that what you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `.find()`always returns the first instance of the given key. So let's say your string is something like `bobabob` than your result will be `4`. Because you iterate through your string and for every given letter he searches for the first appearance of the letter. So the first `b` will lead to the first `bob`. The `o` doesn't fulfil the if-statement. then there is another `b`. BUT your if-statement won't look at the string from the second `b` and then 3 chars further...it will use the first appearance of `b`, so u get the `bob` from the beginning...

I hope you understand what I am trying to say! To sum up:

When you are looking for `bob` in your string and the first appearance ob a `b` is part of a `bob` combination, the print will give you the amount of `b`s in your string, because every `b` leads the if-statement to the first `bob`. If your first `b` is NOT part of a `bob` combination,  for an eg. `breadbobbob`, your result will always be `0`

An easy way to solve that would be with `s.count("bob")`

Answer (score 0):

- If you don't want overlapping count, use `str.count()`. Example:

```
>>> "bobob".count("bob")
1
```

- If you want overlapping count, use regex. Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "bobob"
>>> len(re.findall('(?=bob)', text))
2
```